# How can I access the array of predicted addresses from Google Maps once an address is entered?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geocoding, google-maps-api

The Google Maps JavaScript Autocomplete API mentions that autocomplete [returns an array of prediction objects](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete).  How can I access this array without autocomplete?  I have a standard HTML form with address fields (like house number, street name, city, etc.).  The information is passed into a JavaScript function that concatenates the fields into a street address, then geocodes the address using the Google Geocoding API.